# Как сделать такую смену классов и блоков?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Суть такая: есть 4 кнопки с одинаковыми классами и есть класс `active`; при клике на одну из кнопок, нужно добавлять ей класс `active` и отображать блок который нужно отобразить. При следующем клике на вторую кнопку, с первой кнопке снять класс `active` и повесить его второй кнопке, а так же отобразить уже другой блок на том же месте. Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  $('.block').removeClass('active').addClass('none');
  $('#block-'+$(this).attr('data-id')).removeClass('none').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  display:block;
}
.none{
  display:none;
}
#block-1{
 background:red;
}
#block-2{
 background:green;
}
#block-3{
 background:blue;
}
#block-4{
 background:yellow;
}
.button{
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-1" class="block active">1</div>
<div id="block-2" class="block none">2</div>
<div id="block-3" class="block none">3</div>
<div id="block-4" class="block none">4</div>
<hr>
<div class="button" data-id="1">Кнопка 1</div>
<div class="button" data-id="2">Кнопка 2</div>
<div class="button" data-id="3">Кнопка 3</div>
<div class="button" data-id="4">Кнопка 4</div>
```

Comment: а на js как будет?

Comment: @Евгений так он в ответе. Первый блок.

Comment: это же jQuery, я его не использую

Comment: @Евгений Jquery не JS?) Перед вами  один из вариантов логики реализующая вашу задачу (отработает во всех броузерах). Переписать на чистый js вы не можете?

Comment: уже этим занимаюсь)